# swapping two vector's elements in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I have two vectors, `v1 (1x9)` and `v2 (1x4)`.

I have to write a function with two inputs, `(x,y)` and output of `out`.

`x` should be the index number `x` in `v1`.

`y` should be the index number `y` in `v2`.

The function should replace the `xth` element in `v2` with the `yth`element in `v1` and give the new `v2` as output.

As an example:

```
v1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
v2=[1 2 3 4];
out = myfun(7,2);
```

then the output should be

```
out = [1 7 3 4];
```

The next time if `x=9` and `y=1`

```
out = myfun(9,1);
out = [9 7 3 4];
```

my main program idea is

[M Z]=test(A,q)
          A is matrix (mxn)
   q is  vector of length m 
    i=[1:m];j=[1:n];
          c(:,j)=q./A(:,j);
          find minimum element in c .  as example it is c(I,j) then
         x=I;  and y=j;g
         i = [1:x-1,x+1:m];  j = [1:y-1,y+1:n];  % starting new calculations
statements…calculation procedures to find matrix M instead of A and vector Z instead of q.

end of program

now I want to write myfunction which you did before inside this program

```
   elseif v(x) <= v1(n)  this program must working continuously (holding M and Z as new A and q in input and get the minimum ratio and so the new x and y ) until   v(x)==n break
```

please help

Comment: `v2(y) = v1(x);` is not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `save` the variable and `load` it in the next call.

```
function v2 = myfun(x,y)
v1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]; 
v2=[1 2 3 4];
if exist('v2.mat', 'file' ) ~= 0
   load('v2')
end
v2(y) = v1(x);
save('v2','v2');
end
```

You could also use `persistant variable`,

```
function out = myfun(x,y)
persistent v
if isempty(v)
   v = [1 2 3 4];
end
v1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
v(y) = v1(x);
out = v;
end
```

**Note**

> **mlock command** locks the currently running function in memory so that subsequent clear functions do not remove it. Locking a function in memory also prevents any persistent variables defined in the file from getting reinitialized.

**Edit**

I got this form your comments, see how it goes,

```
function out = test(x,y) 
persistent v 
if isempty(v) 
   v = [1 2 3 4]; 
end
v1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
v(y) = v1(x);
if x == 3;
   out = v;
   return 
elseif v(y) <= v1(9)
   statements 
end
out = v;
end
```

Comment: kamtal ,, I edited my question , I need you to see it ,,and helpe

Comment: @osman please ask a new question, put the code you already have and ask what you are trying to do. So others could help too. It's getting really messy. Enter the codes using `` so it would be readable. thanks,

Comment: hi; I have problem in this line i = [1:x-1,x+1:m];j = [1:en-1,en+1:n]; warning : Warning: Colon operands must be real scalars. what is that mean please help

Comment: ok; but if I have x=3 and en=6  and m=4 and n=9 then this warning coming in this line i = [1:x-1,x+1:m];
j = [1:en-1,en+1:n]; why??

Comment: @osman, It won't give an error, `i=[1:2,4:4]; j=[1:5,7:9]`. You can try it.

Comment: it doesn't works, I used these loops to construct new matrix inside my function and it received those x and en, but in the last step it gives this warning with wrong just one number,,can I used other format method than these brackets [ ]?how to express this brackets in other way

Comment: @osman, what do you mean by `i = [1:x-1,x+1:m];`? what is the desired output for that?

Comment: (x,en) is the index of pivot element , the desired output is to calculate new matrix in same dimension (mxn) by some operations like multiplication and division depending on those I and j and pivot index, like M(x,j) =A(x,en)\A(x,j);

Comment: @osman, okey but what does `j=[1:5,7:9]` supposed to do? it just gives `j=1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9`. Is that what you want?

Comment: OK. j suppose to go from column one to column 5 and step over 6 then from column 7 to 9,,,, and I same likely in rows and step over x index

Comment: it gives two warning in I and two warning in j , I thought there 2nd iterate in I and he found 4:4 in the next time also?how can I write I and j in for loop format?

Comment: if I found the indices x and en every time by this command [x,en]=find(c==d), how to make en unique? I found the prblm in repeated en please help

Comment: @osman, what do you mean by unique? Just select one? then use `x=x(1) , en=en(1)`.

Comment: I mean if in the 1st time x=3 ,,now in the 4th time if also x=3 then reject it do not accept duplicated value,,

Comment: @osman, okey save previous values of `x` somewhere the check the new value if it matches then discard.